# How did this ZIP file print to my command line when I extracted it?

Tags: debian, zip

I downloaded a font from [www.fontspace.com](http://www.fontspace.com) today.  It came in a basic `.zip` file and so I moved it into its own new folder to extract it (I'm tired of extracting things just to find that they were compressed with everything being in the root of the compressed file and thus they barf all over my desktop).  Upon extracting them with the `unzip` command, ASCII art was printed out into my terminal like in the picture below:

[image]

Only a font was extracted.  How was this art/text put into the zip file?  Is it safe to assume that this is a printed thing only and that unzipping a `.zip` file doesn't actually execute code (thus assuming that [fontspace](http://www.fontspace.com) then wrote a bunch of print statements *vs.* just writing in a text block when zipping the file to later be printed by a built in zip feature)?

For what it's worth, I'm running on a `Debian` based Linux distribution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Zip archives can contain comments, either per file or for the whole archive. Unix unzip displays this comment by default when you manipulate the file (e.g.: when extracting).

To add a multi-line comment you can use the `-z` flag

For more information look at the [zip manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zip)